# What is the Android Studio Master Password?

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords

I want to generate a signed APK. I have created keystore file. And when I generate signed APK it asks for keystore file, alias, password. I fill all the details in and when I click next it ask for "Master Password" so what is the "Master Password?

Comment: I think this is the password you set up with "Android Studio". They have some sort of built-in password manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Your Master Password** is the key to your **encrypted database**. 
>   This is the only password you will need to remember, and it is critical that you do not lose or forget this password.

when You reset this password all app keys and alias will be lost

**Reset Master Password**

> Goto    **settings-> system settings -> passwords**

Under Disk storage protection You can see **Master password** button click it

In dialog click on reset

[image]

Comment: sorry but i don't know what is encrypted database and why it need Master password. Because I have not used any database in my app

Comment: database is for storing app key and alias  passwords  so that you no need to enter every time

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge, when we set Master password.or it automatically got generated

Comment: Android Studio prompts your for the master password the first time you enter credentials (either for signed APK generation or version control pushs/checkouts)

Comment: yes @WilliMentzel is right its better to ask your previous devs for the password (or reset the master password)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to reset your password, in case Android Studio is not asking you for the initial setting of the master password. Given the fact that you still know your **Key store password** and **Key password**, of course.

1. File -> Settings -> Type "password" in search. The appropriate entry will be highlighted.
2. Click on master password -> leave empty -> click OK.
3. Click on master password again -> reset -> enter new password

Additional information:
The internal password manager of Android Studio, to which this (Master) password belongs, is just for convenience, so you don't have to enter your **Key store password** and **Key password** each time you generate a signed APK. It can also save your repository credentials for you.

Comment: hope I recalled the settings correctly, if not please correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the password you set at some point of time for important Android Studio functions like pushing the project to github . For me whenever I want to push the project it asks for the master password .

Comment: But i haven't set any git or github in project

Comment: You can try resetting it when it prompts you to enter password.